# Including javascript within mustache template

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have a block of javascript for displaying adverts that I wish to include every nth time on a page.

I'm using Mustache as my templating language but cannot work out how to include the js so it runs as a script rather than just being inserted as a string.

```
<script id="mustache-post-advert" type="text/mustache">
<article id="post-{{id}}" class="post">

    {{{  <script type="text/javascript">GA_googleFillSlot("MPU")</script>  }}}

</article>

</script>
```

I've tried triple { which I hoped would escape but sadly it didn't.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your json-input should reference the script to call:

### JSON

```
 var json = {
   id: "someid",
   gaFillSlot: function(){
     GA_googleFillSlot("MPU");
   }
 }
```

### TEMPLATE

```
 <script id="mustache-post-advert" type="text/mustache">
   <article id="post-{{id}}" class="post">
     {{gaFillSlot}}
   </article>
 </script>
```

Make sure 'GA_googleFillSlot' is available to be called from the context of mustache at time of templating.

This is in line with the logic-less nature of Mustache: any logic you want should be embedded into the json you pass to Mustache to bgin with.

Didn't test this, but this should work. 
HTH

Comment: That was it, had to tweak the function slightly to meet my needs but you sent me on the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

You're already inside a script tag, there's no need to add another:

```
<script id="mustache-post-advert" type="text/mustache">
  <article id="post-{{id}}" class="post">
    {{ GA_googleFillSlot("MPU") }}
  </article>
</script>
```

**edit**

on second thought, this may not be enough; see here for info on calling functions from within mustache templates:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-using-the-mustache-template-library/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I assume {{ GA_googleFillSlot("MPU") }} would fail as double {{ is a variable. I can't see anything within that link that would help.